# При делении на миллион переменная принимает не то значение

Tags: java

Вот что получается при `i22=1`, `i23=1` - `1.0E-6 3^м`

```
if (e.getSource() == b30) {
    i22 = Double.parseDouble(t19.getText());
    i23 = Double.parseDouble(t21.getText());
    i24 = i23 / i22;
    i25 = i24 * 0.000001;
    if (i22 == 0 || i23 == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Объем = 0.0 3^м");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Объем = "+i25+" 3^м");
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне бы хотелось 0.000001

Comment: Можно как-то это сделать?

Comment: String.format("0.000000000", i25) - что-то такое, поэкспериментируйте с первым параметром.

Comment: Я не знаком с данной структурой, однако очень нужно до завтра сделать этот код рабочим. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: С какой структурой? Классом String?

Comment: Что такое String.format

Comment: Я понимаю, что я идиот, но мне просто необходимо решение этой проблемы.

Comment: Посмотрите на это: https://ideone.com/QBWBeW

Comment: Я всё равно не понял. ((((

Comment: Я понимаю, что многого прошу, но пожалуйста скажите прямо как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Я настолько безмозглый. Можете сказать как это сделать?